# Checkbox data-bind return two values?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get ID and checkbox status ( I have CSS as a Button [CSS Button](https://fiddle.jshell.net/NA7KR/72pvL2jq/9/))

Button name and if active

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ioValue" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="io1">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="io1">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

The button works and show true false, I can not work out how to get the ID

```
 self.ioEvent = function(data, event) {
           console.log(1)
           console.log(data)

           console.log(data[0])
           console.log(data[1])

           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {"io": data[0], "status": data[1]},
                url: "/plugin/test/setIOcheckbox",       
                async: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: FYI trying to make a plugin for Octoprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**event.target.id** should give you the "ID"